# How does postgreSQL structure Django Array Fields in database

Tags: django, postgresql

How does PostgreSQL structure an ArrayField like:

```
class House(models.Model):
    people_ids = ArrayField(models.IntegerField(), default=list, blank=True)
```

in database? Does it generate an auxiliary table with the numbers as Ids and then another table with the Id pairs? Like:

House

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | MyHouse |

People

| Id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

House_People

| House_Id | Person_Id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |

So as to have, for example, people 1 and 2 in house "MyHouse"?